# Integrator Key to migrate to Production

Tags: docusignapi

On the REST API Certification Checklist, it asks "Integrator Key to migrate to Production". What does this mean? Wouldn't we use the same integrator key we use in our demo account?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be the same integrator key that you're using in Demo. The end result of the (successful) certification process is that the Integrator Key you've been using in Demo is also approved for use in Production.